# Building/Bundling an Angular 2 application for a .NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-mvc-5, angular-cli, .net-4.6

I currently have an angular '2' application inside of a .NET 4.6 project. It is working nicely however I have question with regards to bundling.
The application was created using the latest angular CLI and I have a preference to building/bundling the application with it. The bundle's webpack creates are fantastic from my experience.

My question to you is do you have any recommendations/idea's with regards to bundling and thus consuming this bundle in a .NET MVC application?
I have seen some other threads where developers have used a gulp file that does the ng build command then transports this output to another location to be consumed.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thomas

Comment: On a smaller project I used `tsc` to get ts -> js, some bash command to move the html files from the TS folders to the JS folders and then rollup.js to bundle it all up. All those commands could be grouped into a single `npm run build-my-bundle` command, but I think doing it with gulp would be the cleaner way to go.

Comment: That would work to a degree but the awesomeness of webpack shouldn't be ignored!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this. I have implemented what I think is a clean solution.

For any that are interested, my answer is below:

1. Have an 'angular' folder at the root of your project, or any other name you wish to choose.
2. Inside of this you have your angular-cli.json and package.json files.
3. In the case that you are creating a nuget package later down the line for a deployment (most likely not) then set the "outDir" in your angular/src/app/tsconfig.json to "../out-tsc". This means you can add the "dist" folder to the package without including the 'out-tsc' folder as well.
4. You must have the angular cli installed globally in your user account's npm folder. Run npm install -g @angular/cli to do this.
5. Have a blank index.html at the angular/src level. (unless you specifically need to add something to this).
6. Configure your root tsconfig (of your .net project) to exclude the 'angular' folder.
7. You need to set up a pre-build event in your .csproj. This needs to cd into the angular directory, run npm install, then ng build if in debug, or ng build --prod if in release. To determine if your proj is in debug/release the macro is $(ConfigurationName). For my solution I created a powershell script that took the ConfigurationName as an argument and ran npm install then ng build. I ran this script as a pre-build event in the .csproj. You could add the global install of the angular cli here as well but I skipped this.
8. To include your bundled angular files into your MVC view I used an import link:

`<link rel="import" href="/angular/dist/index.html">`

This doesn't work in browsers other than chrome so I added a polyfill above it. This polyfill is from webcomponentsjs:

```
<script async src="~/Scripts/polyfills/webcomponentsjs/lite.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="import" href="/angular/dist/index.html">
```

The resulting view:

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

 <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

<script async src="~/Scripts/polyfills/webcomponentsjs/lite.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="import" href="/angular/dist/index.html">
```

Now when you build then boot up your .NET MVC application and go to this view your angular application will appear.

Kind regards